# Groovy, specify index limit with eachWithIndex

Tags: groovy

actually working on table where is a few sections with rows from 1-4, and I need to specify at which index should it end. Like there is 4 rows to be completed, and if someone would like to add next value, it shouldn't show up. [how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msvQ1.png)

```
 name.eachWithIndex { elem, int i4 ->
    def idx = i4 + 4

    ctx.append("something[${idx}]something", something)
}
```

at this point, I define from what point to index

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Try to write the sample so that we can run it, then we can figure out what you have and what you need.